# Search Builder extension of DataTables does not save values

Tags: datatables

I am using the SearchBuilder extension to filter data.

Because I am also using sever-side processing, I force a search only when the user presses the enter key, like [example](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchbuilder/examples/initialisation/returnSearch.html).

But when I click button ">" to add new criteria, the previous value is empty.

Any suggestion for me?

Here my code:

I use search:{true} to force search only search only user press enter

```
$table = $(`#${_options.table.id}`).DataTable({
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        search: {
            return: true
        },
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true,
        "filter": true,
        "pageLength": 2,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "ajax": {
            "url": _options.table.urls.load,
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "ordering": true,
        "order": [[2,'asc']],
        //"order": [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc']]
        "columns":[
                        {
                            "data": null,
                            "orderable": false,
                            "searchable": false,
                            "className": "text-center",
                            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                let html = `<div class="icheck-primary input-group" style="display:block;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="example1_${meta.row}">
                                                <label for="example1_${meta.row}"></label>
                                            </div>`;
                                return html;
                            },
                            searchBuilderType: 'html'
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "id",
                            "name": "Mã số",
                            "autoWidth": true,
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": false
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "title",
                            "name": "Tên danh mục",
                            "autoWidth": true,
                            searchBuilderType: 'string'
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "created",
                            "name": "Ngày tạo",
                            "autoWidth": true,
                            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return new Date(data).toLocaleDateString("vi-VN");
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "modified",
                            "name": "Ngày chỉnh sữa",
                            "autoWidth": true,
                            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return new Date(data).toLocaleDateString("vi-VN");
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "active",
                            "name": "Hoạt động",
                            "autoWidth": true,
                            "className": "text-center",
                            "width": "10%",
                            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                let html = `<div class="icheck-primary input-group" style="display:block;">
                                                <input disabled type="checkbox" ${data ? 'checked' : ''} id="example1_active_${meta.row}" name="terms">
                                                <label for="example1_active_${meta.row}"></label>
                                            </div>`;
                                return html;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "orderable": false,
                            "width": "15%",
                            "className": "text-center",
                            "data": null,
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return `<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="Edit('${row.id}',  '${row.title}');" href="#">Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="Delete('${row.id}', '${row.title}');" >Delete</a>`;
                            }
                        }
                    ],
        "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
            let checkbox = $(row).children('td').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]');
            let headerCheckbox = $($table.column().header()).find('input[type=checkbox]');


            headerCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
            checkbox.on('change', { rowIndex: dataIndex }, function (e) {
                let checked = $(this).prop('checked');
                let headerCheckbox = $($table.column().header()).find('input[type=checkbox]');

                let tableId = $table.table().node().id;
                let deletebutton = $(`button[aria-controls = ${tableId}][name=delete]`);

                let rowIdx = e.data.rowIndex;
                if (checked) {
                    $table.rows(rowIdx).select();
                    $count++;
                    if ($count == $table.rows().count()) {
                        headerCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    deletebutton.attr('disabled', false);
                }
                else {
                    $table.rows(rowIdx).deselect();
                    $count--;
                    if ($count == 0) {
                        deletebutton.attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                    headerCheckbox.prop('checked', false);

                }
            });
        },
        "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
            // Add custom button into table wrapper
            $table.buttons().container().appendTo(`#${_options.table.id}_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)`);

            //Select all bycheckbox header
            let headerCheckbox = $($table.column().header()).find('input[type=checkbox]');
            headerCheckbox.on('change', { settings: settings }, function (e) {
                let checked = $(this).prop('checked');
                for (let i = 0; i < $table.rows().count(); i++) {
                    $($table.rows(i).column().nodes()[i]).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', checked);
                }
                let deletebutton = $(`button[aria-controls = ${_options.table.id}][name=delete]`).attr('disabled', !checked);
                (checked) ? $table.rows().select() : $table.rows().deselect();
            });
        },
        "responsive": true,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        language: {
            searchBuilder: {
                button: {
                    0: 'Criteria',
                    1: 'Criteria (one selected)',
                    _: 'Criteria (%d)'
                }
            }
        },
        "buttons": [
            {
                text: `<i class="fas fa-plus"> New</i>`,
                className: 'btn btn-primary form-group',
                attr: {
                    'name': 'new',
                    'style': 'background: #007bff !important; border-color: #007bff !important'
                },
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    ajaxFormAction(_options.modal.selector, _options.modal.id, 'Create new category', '/Admin/Category/Create', true, function (e) {
                        $table.draw();
                    });
                    
                }
            },
            {
                text: `<i class="fas fa-trash"> Delete</i>`,
                className: 'btn btn-danger form-group',
                attr: {
                    'name': 'delete',
                    "disabled": true
                },
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    let ids = [];
                    let rows = $table.rows({ selected: true }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                        ids.push(this.data().id);
                    });
                    ids = ids.join(',');
                    ajaxDelete(ids, null, _options.table.urls.delete, function (e) {
                        $table.draw();
                    });
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Filter',
                className: 'btn btn-default form-group',
                extend: 'searchBuilder'
            }
        ]            
    })
    $('<input id="example1_column" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="aaaa" />').insertBefore($("#example1_filter input"));
    return $table
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the code we need to recreate your problem. When I build a DataTable using `serverSide: true` and Search Builder, I do not have any problems with empty values, after clicking the `>` button.

Comment: hi @andrewjames I have jus edited with my code.

Comment: OK, my apologies - I should have asked for a [mre] - what you have provided is too much code. Please just show the **minimum** amount of code that is needed to recreate the problem.

Comment: hi @andrewjames, I found the way to fix it. Because I configure "search:{return: true}" therefore the value is only saved after I press Enter key. I just go through the code of "searchbuilder" extension and custom it before enter key is pressed. Thank you